# Driving time API other than google directions?

Tags: driving-directions, driving-distance

I have an application where I should have the driving time between a point A and a set of points. I have the GPS coordinates of all these points.
I tried to do the job using google maps directions api, but the problem is that the program must wait for a minimum of 1 second between two consecutive requests, so if the destination set contains 40 points I should wait 39 seconds before getting all the answers.

This part of the program is critical so 39 seconds will be a very long time.

Is there any other api that I can use for this?

Note that I'm not interested in detailed directions or distance, the total travel time will be enough, I can later use google directions on the best answer to get these details.

Thanks!

Comment: I am using Bing Maps Api.

Answer (score 0):

There's [Walk Score's Travel Time API](http://www.walkscore.com/professional/travel-time-api.php) which seems to offer just that

> The Travel Time API rapidly calculates travel times between an origin and a set of destinations. The distance calculator uses ... driving distance ...